# Magento doesn't add values to input fields in custom module edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, edit

I am creating a custom magento module for the backend part, everything is working fine so far, except the fact that when I want to edit an item, on the edit page the form is not populated with values. I did not manage to find a working solution online, hope someone can help me.

This is my `Mymodule/Wine/Block/Adminhtml/Wine/Edit/Tab/Form`

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Wine_Block_Adminhtml_Wine_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('wine_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('wine')->__('Upload .xls Settings')));

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('wine')->__('TItle'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'title',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('filename', 'file', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('wine')->__('File .xls '),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'file'
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWineData()) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWineData());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setWineData(null);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('wine_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('wine_data')->getData());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

The **edit** and **save** actions in `Mymodule/Wine/controllers/Adminhtml/WineController.php`

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $wineId      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $wineModel = Mage::getModel('wine/wine')->load($wineId);

        if ($wineModel->getId() || $wineId == 0) {
            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWineData(true);

            Mage::register('wine_data', $wineModel);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('wine/items');
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('.xls Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('.xls Manager'));
            // $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Managerxxx'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Managerxxx'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('wine/adminhtml_wine_edit'))
                  ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('wine/adminhtml_wine_edit_tabs'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('wine')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            try {
                $wineModel = Mage::getModel('wine/wine');
                $fileName  = '';

                if (isset($_FILES['file']['filename']) && $_FILES['file']['filename'] != '') {
                    try {
                        $path       = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'xls' . DS;
                        $fileName= $_FILES['file']['filename'];
                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('file');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('XLS', 'xls', 'TXT', 'txt'));
                        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $uploader->save($path, $fileName);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('wine')->__($fileName . ' Invalid file format'));
                        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                        return;
                    }
                }

                $wineModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                            ->setName($postData['title'])
                            ->setStatus(0) // $postData['status']P
                            ->setCreated_at(now())
                            ->setExecuted_ad(now())
                            ->setFilename($fileName)
                            ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setWineData(false);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setWineData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

class Mymodule_Wine_Block_Adminhtml_Wine_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('wine_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('wine')->__('Upload .xls Settings')));

        $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'label'     => $this->__('TItle'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'title',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('filename', 'file', array(
            'label'     => $this->__('File .xls '),
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'file'
        ));

        if ($data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWineData(false)) {
            $form->setValues($data);
        } elseif (Mage::registry('wine_data')) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('wine_data')->getData());
        }
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

I have also simplified some of your code down bottom as well. If your form still doesn't prepopulate, then you need to dump your two data sources and make sure that `title` and `file` actually exist and contain a value.

Comment: It works with your code, and with mine also, it was just that the index names were different. You have to be really careful in magento. Thanks for the answer.